# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in android while getting image from gallery in android

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, out-of-memory, image-capture

I am picking a picture from gallery using code

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gallery);

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(i, SELECT_PICTURE);
    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Log.v("picturePath", "picturePath: " + picturePath);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);

            Intent intentUpload = new Intent(GalleryActivity.this, UploadActivity.class);
            // intentUpload.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
            MyApplicationGlobal.bitmap = bitmap;
            startActivity(intentUpload);
            finish();
        }
    }


public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

But I'm getting error

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:493)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:299)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:324)
at com.markphoto_activities.GalleryActivity.onActivityResult(GalleryActivity.java:59)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4541)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2740)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2787)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1032)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Log-cat is

```
: E/dalvikvm-heap(2487): Out of memory on a 17915920-byte allocation.
"main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
| group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x400d5638 self=0x126c8
| sysTid=2487 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1342909336
| schedstat=( 2650512000 283442000 1204 ) utm=226 stm=39 core=1
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:493)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:299)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:324)
at com.markphoto_activities.GalleryActivity.onActivityResult(GalleryActivity.java:59)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4541)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2740)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2787)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1032)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
: D/skia(2487): libjpeg error 105 <  Ss=%d, Se=%d, Ah=%d, Al=%d> from allocPixelRef [3456   2592]
  : D/skia(2487): --- decoder->decode returned false
  : D/AndroidRuntime(2487): Shutting down VM
```

Comment: @DipakKeshariya hey, your answer is correct and exact what I wanted. But Pratik's answer is little bit more better. So I have accepted it, and sorry I can't accept another, so only upvoted

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this :

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                try {
                    picImageView.setImageBitmap(decodeUri(selectedImage));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And then declare the following function :

```
private Bitmap decodeUri(Uri selectedImage) throws FileNotFoundException {
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o);

        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 100;

        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                break;
            }
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o2);
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, I've seen this code snippet before on SO: `while(true)` with an `if(condition)` to `break;`, and it really hurts my eyes. You could simply put the opposite condition in the while loop, so you don't need that break anymore. In this case: `while (!(width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)) {...}` Cheers =) 

This makes your code much more readable AND it's semantic(!). Feel free to share your thoughts, I hope you guys understand what I wanted to make clear.

Comment: how to know reqHeight and reqWidth? I mean do we need to fix it to static value? or we can change those w.r.t devices?

Answer (score 2):

Add below function into your java file and call this function in `onActivityResult()` after getting image path or image uri, it will solve your problem.

```
private Bitmap decodeUri(Uri selectedImage) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
            getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o);

    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 100;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
            break;
        }
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
            getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o2);
}
```

Comment: how to know reqHeight and reqWidth? I mean do we need to fix it to static value? or we can change those w.r.t devices?

Answer (score 2):

try this way...

```
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultcode, Intent intent)
 {
     int orientation =0;
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultcode, intent);

     if (requestCode == 1)
     {
         if (intent != null && resultcode == RESULT_OK)
         {             

               Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();

               String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
               Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
               cursor.moveToFirst();
               int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
               String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
               Log.v("log","filePath is : "+filePath);

               cursor.close();
               try 
               {
                    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
                     orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+orientation, 1).show();
                    Log.v("log", "ort is "+orientation);

               } 
               catch (IOException e)
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

               if(bmp != null && !bmp.isRecycled())
               {
                   bmp = null;               
               }

               File f = new File(filePath);

               bmp = decodeFile(f,300,420);
       }
     }
   }
```

and this is the decode function...

```
public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f,int WIDTH,int HIGHT){
     try {
         //Decode image size
         BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
         o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
         BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

         //The new size we want to scale to
         final int REQUIRED_WIDTH=WIDTH;
         final int REQUIRED_HIGHT=HIGHT;
         //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
         int scale=1;
         while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_WIDTH && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_HIGHT)
             scale*=2;

         //Decode with inSampleSize
         BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
         o2.inSampleSize=scale;
         return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
     return null;
 }
```

Comment: how to know reqHeight and reqWidth? I mean do we need to fix it to static value? or we can change those w.r.t devices?